# How do I show a gif attachment in Discord bot message embed?

Tags: discord.js

Currently, my bot is set to send an embed message each time a command is used, but for some reason, the gif is not showing. This is what my code looks like:

```js
let ballembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(0x000000)
  .setDescription(`**${mention}** was just harshly bonked!`)
  .attachFiles("https://media.giphy.com/media/JrkbVRQA5adwle1ykt/giphy.gif")
message.channel.send(ballembed);
```

The code works fine if it's a png, but will not show if I use a gif.

What happens is that the embed message sends itself but without the gif, and there are no errors in the terminal.

I've tried using `.attachFiles` however, what happens is that the gif sends *outside* of the embed message.

I would like to be able to send the embed message with the gif inside.

Comment: Try using `.setImage()` instead of `.attachFiles()`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you, I've tried `.setImage()` too but gif still doesn't show up, the message itself sends fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.setImage` like Lily suggested or use an array instead like intended

```js
.attachFiles(["https://media.giphy.com/media/JrkbVRQA5adwle1ykt/giphy.gif"]);
```

Comment: Hello! I've tried as suggested, but the gif still only shows up on the outside of the embed. The message itself sends fine.

Comment: Just looked at docs and yep, it's intended for outside of the message. I've tried `setThumbnail` and `setImage`, which do not work. The issue might be that the link is not a direct link to a gif but its a link to giphy which has a gif as an `element`, this way discord can't tell the gif.

Comment: Yep I have tested this out and it is so, test out this link: https://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/agif1opt.gif, which is a direct link to a gif and it works with `setThumbnail` and `setImage`

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed all my links and it works now! Thank you!