# How do I embed a random gif out of preset gifs for my discord js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a custom discord bot for my server, and I want to have some fun commands. One is a variant of the ban command, where it will also include a gif when responding to the ban. I'm just not sure how to implement what I'm looking for, let alone in my existing code.

I've included the entirety of my ban command. The location in which I would like for it to occur would be in the banConfirmationEmbed.

Can anyone help me out?

```
module.exports = {
name: 'bigban',
description: "An extra fun ban command!",
execute(message, args, Discord){
    const args = mesage.content.split(' ').slice(1);

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const banReason =args.slice(1).join;

    if (!user) {
        try {
            if (!message.guild.members.get(args.slice(0,1).join(' '))) throw new Error('I\'m sorry, I could not get a Discord user with this userID.');
            user = message.guild.members.get(args.slice(0, 1).join(' '));
            user = user.user;
        } catch (error) {
            return message.reply('I\'m sorry, I could not get a Discord user with this userID.');
        }
    }
    if (user === message.author) return message.channel.send('Congratulations, you\'ve tried to big ban yourself.');
    if (!reason) return message.reply('Dude, you have to tell me why this moron deserves a big ban.');
    if (!message.guild.member(user).bannable) return message.reply('You cannot big ban this user, as you are not dank enough.');

    await message.guild.ban(user)

    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const banConfirmationEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(0x7c22c0)
    .setDescription(' ${usertag} got phocin BIG banned.');
    message.channel.send({
        embed: banConfirmationEmbed
    });

    const modlogChannelID = '852638799694659614';
    if (modlogChannelID.lenght !== 0) {}
        if (!clientInformation.channels.get(modlogChannelID )) return undefined;

        const banConfirmationEmbedModLog = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Banned by **${msg.author.username}#${msg.author.discriminator}**', msg.author.displayAvatarURL)
        .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL)
        .setColor(0x7c22c0)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setDescription('**Action**: Ban'
            + '**User: ${user.username}#{user.discriminator} (${user.id})'
            + '**Reason**: ${reason}');
        clientInformation.channels.get(modlogChannelID).send({
            embed: banConfirmationEmbedModLog
        });
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show a gif attachment in Discord bot message embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236787/how-do-i-show-a-gif-attachment-in-discord-bot-message-embed)

Comment: To clarify, I am aware of how to include a singular gif, that is not what I want to do. I want to bot to pull a random gif from a list I have set.